# Convert latin1_bin to utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql

How can **convert** data from **latin1_bin** to utf8_general_ci?

actual info_hash is "`pŠ »øæv£EcÜÿïS¢ûî`"

i will convert to  new info_hash "`8406c2b8a158693cc965e568fe30a40036f22456`"

thanks

Comment: Can you show how `pŠ »øæv£EcÜÿïS¢ûî` suppose to be converted to `8406c2b8a158693cc965e568fe30a40036f22456`, because it is definitely not just encoding mismatch?

Comment: yes, how ?  someone has done something to me.